# xamarin.android navigation drawer list not detecting ItemClick Events

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, navigation-drawer, onitemclick

I have successfully created a custom side navigation menu with icons. I now want to detect item click events on the list so as to start new activities from the dashboard activity but the SelectItem method does not fire on item click.

This is my SideMenu method that creates the navigation drawer

```
private void SideMenu()
{
 string[] appActions = new string[]{"Transactions", "Budgeting","Invoicing", "Bills", "\n", "Reminders", "\n", "Reports", "Accounts", "\n", "Logout" };

    int[] icons = new int[]{Resource.Drawable.sidenavtransactions, Resource.Drawable.sidenavbudget, Resource.Drawable.sidenavinvoicing, Resource.Drawable.sidenavbills, Resource.Drawable.trans, Resource.Drawable.sidenavreminders, Resource.Drawable.trans, Resource.Drawable.trans, Resource.Drawable.trans, Resource.Drawable.trans, Resource.Drawable.trans };

    actions = new List<Actions> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < icons.Length; i++) {
        Actions action = new Actions ();
        action.actionName = appActions[i];
        action.actionIcon = icons[i];
        actions.Add (action);
    }
    drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout> (Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
    drawerList = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.left_drawer);
    drawerList.Adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter (this, actions);

    drawerList.ItemClick += (sender, e) => SelectItem(e.Position);


    ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled (true);
    ActionBar.SetHomeButtonEnabled (true);

    drawerToggle = new MyActionBarDrawerToggle (this, drawer, Resource.Drawable.hamburger, Resource.String.DrawerOpen, Resource.String.DrawerClose);

    drawerToggle.DrawerClosed += delegate {
        ActionBar.Title = title;
        InvalidateOptionsMenu ();
    };

    drawerToggle.DrawerOpened += delegate {
        ActionBar.Title = drawerTitle;
        drawerList.BringToFront();
        drawer.RequestLayout();
        InvalidateOptionsMenu();
    };

    drawer.SetDrawerListener (drawerToggle);
}
```

This is the SelectItem method that is supposed to be invoked on item click

```
private void SelectItem(int position)
    {
        switch (position) {
        case 0: 
            Toast.MakeText (this, actions [0].actionName, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            break;
        case 1:
            Toast.MakeText (this, actions [1].actionName, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            break;
        case 2:
            Toast.MakeText (this, actions [2].actionName, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            break;
        case 3:
            Toast.MakeText (this, actions [3].actionName, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            break;
        case 4:
            Toast.MakeText (this, actions [4].actionName, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`on SelectItem()`, have you check if this is triggered at all?
In my cases clicks doesn't work when something else that is inside this view steam focus, for example if you make a custom `ListView` with a checkbox inside then the checkbox might steal the focus and alter the expected behavior.
You must then set `focusable`, `focusableintouchmode` and maybe `clickable` to false in this checkbox. Check if your problem is related to that.

Comment: The SelectItem() method is not being trigerred at all